# proof of convexity of a function if Jensen's Inequality does not hold

Tags: calculus, optimization

I know that a function is convex if the following inequality is true:

$λf(x_1)+(1−λ)f(x_2)≥f(λx_1+(1−λ)x_2)$.

However, if we could find some feasible values of $x_1$ and $x_2$ for which above inequality is reversed, i.e.,$f(λx_1+(1−λ)x_2)≥λf(x_1)+(1−λ)f(x_2)$ then is it sufficient to say $f(x)$ is not a convex? 
Please not that convexity means both (convex, concave).

Comment: Your question is NOt clear to me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $f \colon D \to \mathbf R$ on a convex $D$ is by definition convex if and *only if*
$$ f\bigl((1- \lambda)x_1 + \lambda x_2\bigr) \le (1-\lambda)f(x_1) + \lambda f(x_2), \qquad \text{all } \lambda \in [0,1], x_1, x_2 \in D $$
and concave if and only if 
$$ f\bigl((1- \lambda)x_1 + \lambda x_2\bigr) \ge (1-\lambda)f(x_1) + \lambda f(x_2), \qquad \text{all } \lambda \in [0,1], x_1, x_2 \in D $$
hence, for a function to be not convex it is enough to find $x_1, x_2 \in D$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$ such that 
$$ f\bigl((1-\lambda) x_1 + \lambda x_2\bigr) \mathrel {\color{red}>} (1-\lambda)f(x_1) + \lambda f(x_2). $$
If you more over want $f$ to be not concave, you must give also 
$y_1, y_2 \in D$ and $\mu \in [0,1]$ such that 
$$ f\bigl((1-\mu) y_1 + \mu y_2\bigr) \mathrel {\color{red}<} (1-\mu)f(x_1) + \mu f(y_2). $$
Note, that you need a **strict** inequality here.